# Using D&D maps as a reference for my indie game

Tags: legal, level-design, copyright, intellectual-property

I've been considering using existing D&D battle maps for a commercial indie game I'm developing. I will use them as reference: I will create the same layout with my own assets.

I want to ensure that this practice is respectful to the original creators and the community.

Could you advise on the ethical implications and best practices for this approach?

Comment: What does the copyright say about these maps? Can you contact the author(s) to get there opinion/permission about this?

Comment: @Vaillancourt i mean there are hundreds of maps.
For example there is this website:  https://www.kassoon.com/dnd/battle-maps/ 

But it doesnt say anything about copyright. But When i image search some of these maps, there are people who made it.
So this website just publishes peoples work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally start with maps that are specifically intended for commercial use. For instance:

- Dyson Logos (cartographer for WotC's *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons*) has released over [500 maps under a free, royalty-free, commercial license](https://dysonlogos.blog/maps/commercial-maps/).
- You can also find [commercial use maps on DriveThruRPG](https://preview.drivethrurpg.com/en/browse?keyword=commercial%20maps).

Sticking to these resources is likely your safest route - there's no moral ambiguity or creative legal interpretation. That said, read the licensing information carefully; some may have attribution requirements.

And as mentioned in the comments, in some cases you might be able to contact the cartographers directly. The WotC books list cartographers on the credits page that precedes the table of contents.